# I need help updating

Tags: upgrade, 10.10, setup

I am currently running Ubuntu 10.10 and I would lie to update.  For some reason my computer will not let get into the BiOs setup to install from the DVD of Ubuntu.  Please help

Comment: Do you want to update or fresh install?

Comment: Please refer to your BIOS manual, also remember that [Ubuntu 10.10 reached EOL](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2013-March/000167.html) and is not supported in this site. For upgrade please use the `update-manager` or use a fresh copy of a Stable version of ubuntu and do a clean instalation.

Comment: This question may be closed soon as its about an old unsupported release.  Bios settings vary from computer to computer and as you have not told us what computer you have we can't advise how to change the settings.  I suggest you ask on an hardware related forum providing details of the computer you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to incrementally upgrade.

Here are the instructions to go from 10.10 to 11.04.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades

Continue upgrading to higher versions until 12.04 or above (Since that is what is currently supported).

Answer (score 0):

I think, pressing **F12** or **Esc** key will open boot priority list of your BIOS while boooting your computer before the OS logo appears. You can choose CD-Rom for the 1st device.